# Can someone help me point out what is incorrect about this double LEFT OUTER JOIN query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to count the amount of accounts that currently do not possess a "position" or a "verification". In order to do this I need to perform two left outer joins on both the verifications and positions table. This is the query that I have constructed so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
    "accounts"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "verifications" ON "accounts.id = verifications.account_id" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "positions" ON "accounts.id = positions.account_id"
WHERE "verifications.account_id = null" AND "positions.account_id = null";
```

This seems to not be the correct query. My console produces this error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
SELECT * FROM "accounts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "verifications"
```

It looks like there is a problem at the beginning of the statement near the accounts. I've already checked out some tutorials on double and triple left outer joins and I'm linking onto the correct fields. I'm at a loss as to what could be wrong. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is it mysql or postgresql?

Comment: This is Postgresql. I'll edit the tag, I didn't know there was a difference between the SQL syntax of either.

Comment: on statements the quotes are in wrong places.  `"accounts.id = positions.account_id"` could be: `accounts.id = positions.account_id` without any quotes.  I'd only use quotes if case sensitivity really matters, in all the places you've chosen to use them here. Or if a "Reserved word" situation would arise.  So basically, eliminate them.

Comment: Just remove all `"` and stop using them completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM accounts
LEFT OUTER JOIN verifications
ON accounts.id = verifications.account_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN positions
ON accounts.id = positions.account_id
WHERE verifications.account_id is null AND positions.account_id is null;
```

Comment: Thanks Lashane. This worked perfectly when I queried the database directly. I was using the rails console and apparently it didn't like the query. I was under the impression you could use SQL and rails query methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you want or need to use double quotes do:

```
ON "accounts"."id" = "verifications"."account_id"
```

The double quotes wraps each identifier. Using double quotes is a bad ideia unless there are illegal characters in the identifier (also not that good)

Comment: Thanks Clodoaldo for your response and the heads up about the double quotes. I didn't know that. Much appreciated!